# AWS EC2: Compile vim with clipboard support

Tags: vim, xorg, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I'm using a free EC2 instance using Amazon Linux AMI 2013.09.2. I want to install the latest version of vim and include clipboard support. I've seen a few guides, but none seem to be too current.

From a freshly launched image, I:

```
sudo yum groupinstall 'Development tools'
sudo yum groupinstall 'Development Libraries'
sudo yum install perl-ExtUtils-Embed.x86_64 libxtst-devel
sudo yum install perl-devel python-devel ruby-devel
```

My understanding is that amongst these groups and packages should be everything needed to:

```
sudo ./configure --with-features=huge \
        --enable-rubyinterp \
        --enable-pythoninterp \
        --with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib/python2.7-config \
        --enable-perlinterp \
        --with-x \
        --enable-cscope \
sudo make
sudo make install
```

But `vim --version | grep clip` returns:

```
-clipboard       +iconv           +path_extra      -toolbar  
+eval            +mouse_dec       +startuptime     -xterm_clipboard
```

I checked the config header with `grep X11 auto/config.h`...

```
/* #undef HAVE_X11 */
/* #undef HAVE_X11_SUNKEYSYM_H */
/* #undef HAVE_X11_XPM_H */
/* #undef HAVE_X11_XMU_EDITRES_H */
/* #undef HAVE_X11_SM_SMLIB_H */
/* Define if you want Cygwin to use the WIN32 clipboard, not compatible with X11*/
```

... and the config log with `grep X11 auto/config.log`:

```
configure:7871: checking if X11 header files can be found
configure:9053: checking for X11/SM/SMlib.h
ac_cv_header_X11_SM_SMlib_h=no
```

So, it seems as though config isn't seeing X11 installed, even though it should be available:

```
$ sudo yum install libX11-devel
Package libX11-devel-1.5.0-4.10.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

I'm groping in the dark here, but I'm pretty sure I've identified the right issues. I'm looking for advice on how to complete a compilation of vim from source with `+clipboard` or `+xterm_clipboard`.

PS: Issues persist after `reboot`, then `sudo make clean` and lather-rinse-repeat.

Comment: Develop locally and push your changes remotely. The geek factor of working entirely on the remote machine is not worth the time wasted on the hoops and loops needed to make it all work.